# Disable specific months from selecting in p-calendar primeNG v16

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

I have a p-calendar component in which I want to disable specific months ( let's say all months except 1, ie If Jan, all the months other than January should be disabled for all the years.)
and should not be able to select dates from these months.

Is this actually possible to achieve?

p-calendar have properties like disableDates and disableDays. But trying them i didn't find a solution. Apologies, if I am missing out something. Let me know how to achieve this.